# Does anyone know why my animation renders in Eevee get kinda transparent in certain frames?

Tags: animation, mesh, geometry-nodes

I'm using geometry nodes to make a building and I've tried animating the number of floors the building has.

Every frame where a new floor is introduced, the building looks really weird and in the next frame it's perfectly fine. Check this:

[image]
frame 50
[image]
frame 51

[image]
frame 52

I have some composition options (bloom and AO), but removing them didn't help. I also have bloom, AO and motion blur enabled in my render options, but disabling that didn't help either.

In the viewport, the building looks fine in that certain frame:

[image]

Does anyone know why my renders in Eevee get kinda transparent in certain frames?
Also, when I try to render that specific frame with Cycles, it works fine. Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: can you please provide your blend file so we can check it out?

Comment: Of course, no problem. It's a bit messy, though! :D https://easyupload.io/64m2c6

Comment: Thanks for your blend file. I didn't even know that you can have two group inputs...;) i tried different things...but nothing helped :( i have no idea...sorry.

Comment: Thanks for trying, I appreciate it!

Comment: just for info to others: I could clearly reproduce the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The glitch is caused by the *Motion Blur* setting in the Eevee render settings. Turn it off and the animation will render properly.

It looks like *Motion Blur* can't handle the creation of additional geometry by the *Geometry Nodes*. The error always occurs exactly at the frames where the next floor is built. It seems that Blender tries to morph two frames to simulate motion blur, but the "motion" (actually building the next floor) is too hard for a smooth morph transition within two frames. The frames differ too much. The result is then this semi-transparent overlapping image of two frames.

Motion Blur on:
[image: blur on]

Motion Blur off:
[image: blur off]

Comment: Oh, just noticed that you wrote you already tried to turn off motion blur without success. It works for me when I turn it off. Added images of the render. (Blender 2.93) -

Comment: That's it, I must've done something wrong or maybe it didn't render properly for me the first time. It's working now as expected when I turn the motion blur off! Thanks a lot, it was driving me nuts!

Comment: @ShockwaVe: Please check the checkmark left to Blunder's answer so that other people know that it is the right answer. Thank you.

Comment: My bad, thanks for reminding me!