# Render is not Looking like Viewport

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, geometry-nodes

[image: GeometryNodes_Setup][image: What it Should Look Like][image: bad render]Version: 2.93.0

Base Settings;
Cycles
Supported
GPU

Path Tracing
200 Samples

Open Image Denoiser
Color, Albedo, Normal passes

Light Paths
12
12
12
12
12
0

Then the only other thing adjusted from default is adding motion blur.

Everything renders properly in the viewport, but not in the render. In the screenshots provided above, you'll find that the brick texture and the boolean holes in the floor are not showing up for some batches of frames. What's less apparent in the screenshots is that this issue also affects the lighting the shading drastically between frames as well.

My question is, why is this only happening to half the rendered frames? Is there a quick fix I can try in the meantime? Is it a Geometry Node incompatibility issue or did I mess up my setup? I'm grasping at straws here.

Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: Hi. This question was put on hold because as it stands it is not answerable for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Remember only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly only you know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Please describe in detail what your issue is, possibly supported by [some accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button above. Don't post a comment or ask a new question, editing will automatically put it up for review so it can be reopened.

Comment: *Geometry Nodes* don't work very well with *Motion Blur* in animations. Maybe try without MB? Related Q but Eevee: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/229413/does-anyone-know-why-my-animation-renders-in-eevee-get-kinda-transparent-in-cert/229455#229455